# Help me to move trigger logic into future method in helper class

Tags: apex

I have written trigger to create a contact and assign it community user before user is created. But I am getting mixed DML issue due to the insertion setup&non setup objects in one transation.

Please show me how to move below logic in future method of helper class.
Here is the trigger:

```
trigger CreateContact on User (before insert) {

   List<User> listUser = new List<User>();  
   for (User usr : trigger.new)   
   {  
     if (String.isBlank(usr.contactId))   
     {  
       listUser.add(usr);  
     }  
   }  
   if (listUser.size() > 0)   
   {  
    List<Contact> newContacts = new List<Contact>();  
    Map<String, User> userNameMap = new Map<String, User>();  
     //Create Contact For Each User  
     for (User usr : listUser)   
     {  
       String contactLastName = usr.lastname;  
       userNameMap.put(contactLastName,usr);  
       Contact con = new Contact(LastName = contactLastName);  
       newContacts.add(con);  
     }  
     Insert newContacts;  
     for (Contact con : newContacts)   
     {  
       //Put Contact Id's on Contacts  
       if (userNameMap.containsKey(con.LastName))   
       {  
         userNameMap.get(con.LastName).contactId = con.Id;  
       }  
     }  
   }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first change the trigger event from before insert to after insert.
As you are creating a contact record when the user creation hasn't finished writing a future method may not work in the current context(before insert).

What you can do is to in after insert trigger, once you get the list of users for which contact is to be created call a future method pass list of users as a parameter and move the entire logic in that method.
Once the contact is created update the user record from the list.

**Update to the answer:-**
You can actually assign a test contact while creating user and then in the future method create a real contact and then update the user records. This is a dirty solution but it will help in your case. The point to check will be the performance.

Comment: After insert won't work because ContactId is mandatory field for creating Customer Community plus user.

Comment: You can create a normal user and update it to a community user when the contact creation finishes in the future method.

Comment: can u show me piece of code as an example for idea.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a different way to achieve this requirement.